# How to delete emails with larger file attachments

Tags: gmail, email-attachments

My Gmail account is getting filled up with large emails.

how can I delete larger file sized emails from my gmail account.

or any other work around to save space in my gmail id. 
any API call or any program for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple

search

```
larger:20m
```

20m is file size

and if you need time search use

```
older_by:300d  


larger:20m  older_by:300d
```

will give you files older by 300 days and larger file attachment of 20m

Comment: The `larger:20m` works for me but for the `older_by:300d` I got no emails whereas they are exist.

Answer (score 0):

Base on *[Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)* you can use `size` or `larger` to search any messages larger than a certain size in bytes.

Example

```
size:10000000
```

or

```
larger:10M
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can keep the emails, and just delete the attachments using [Slimbox](https://rok.strnisa.com/slimbox/), a simple cross-platform tool I wrote. Feedback welcome.

Comment: Thanks, but why not open-source your project?

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez The tool has now been open sourced: https://github.com/rokstrnisa/slimbox.